# Joon and AC baggage interline

Tags: canada, luggage, transit-visas, schengen-visas, cdg

I booked a ticket to Toronto (YYZ) from Mumbai (BOM) with a stop over at Paris (CDG). Following is the itinerary:

9W4947 BOM-CDG operated by Joon

AC881 CDG-YYZ

The stop over at CDG is of 2hrs 40min and the itinerary has been booked on a single ticket, although both airlines have a different PNR.

1. Will my baggage be checked through? I am assuming Joon (which is Air France) has interline with Air Canada.
2. Also at BOM, do I check in with Jet Airways (since they sold the ticket) or with Joon/Air France?
3. Will I need a transit visa to change from Terminal 2E to Terminal 1. I saw that since July 2018, Indian citizens do not need a transit visa to transit through French airports. Can someone confirm?
   Thanks.